# Get parameters and custom page template

Tags: url-rewriting, urls, page-template, parameter

My WP website have calendar page with custom page template. If i open mysite.com/cal i see calendar of current month, if i open **mysite.com/cal/?month=01&year=2015** i see calendar for january. It works without any rewrite rules for every month in 2015 but for some reason for any other years i see error that there is no such page.

Why does it happen? How can i solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found where problem was - i can't set other year. All i needed to do is to rename year parameter to something else - for example my_year.